# Twilio DTMF Issue

Tags: twilio, dtmf

We have an application that is written on Twilio, whereby we dial out to a sales reps and announce the contents of the form. We then allow the sales rep to press the '5' key to instantly connect to the person who submitted the form. The first part of this is working perfectly - but we are having more and more issues with the system recognizing that a key is pressed when playing the announcement. Some of them are using VOIP phones. What can we do to make it more reliable so that every time they press the key, it recognizes the tone and starts dialing out immediately? Is There any way to recognize some key is pressed for VOIP phones?

Explaining some more detail in code:

```
<Response> 
 <Gather numDigits="1" timeout="80" method="POST" action="MY_PHP.php"> 
   <Say> Some Announcements and asking to press 5 to connect with person who  submitted the form 
  </Say> 
<Pause length='2'/>
  <Say> Some Announcements and asking to press 5 to connect with person who  submitted the form 
  </Say>
........
.......
 </Gather>
</Response>
```

Above code is working for most of the phones but in some cases like VOIP phones they are pressing 5 but twilio is not recognizing means I am not getting any Digits in MY_PHP.php, It is just announcing my message every time, this message will be play till sales rep not pressing 5 or timeout till 80 seconds . Please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: This question is very broad. I recommend scouring Google first, trying some code bits, then coming back with a specific problem.

Comment: .@WesFoster, I don't agree the question is broad. It is describing a specific problem with Twilio's system not always detecting DTMF. Been using Twilio for some time and I can confirm this is happening.

Comment: Not sure if this is really a problem at Twilio or along the PSTN road not passing the tones.

Comment: Explaining some more detail in code:
<Response>
   <Gather numDigits="1"  timeout="80" method="POST"   action="MY_PHP.php">
</Gather> 
Some Announcements and asking to press 5 to connect with person who submitted the form
</Response>
Above code is working for most of the phones but in some cases like VOIP phones they are pressing 5 but twilio is not recognizing means I am not getting any Digits in MY_PHP.php, It is just announcing my message every time, this message will be play till sales rep not pressing 5 or timeout till 80 seconds .
Please let me know if you need more detail..

Comment: If you are having an issue with this still then I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). They will be able to advise on the DTMF tone problem and make our internal teams aware of the issue too.

Comment: I have already opened a ticket at Twilio, No resolution yet..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work for your case but since you can't be sure that the system recognizes when the '5' key is pressed here is an option.

Change the flow to tell the sales rep. to either hang up or stay on the line to connect to the person who submitted the form. You can then use the [`<Pause>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) to give them time to hang up and if they don't, automatically make the connection.

Or you can try a combination of the `press 5` when it works or `automatically connect` if the sales rep. does not hang up for some time, meaning they want to connect.

Comment: Actually I can't do like that..May be possible there is voice message center and they will not disconnect the phone.

So requirement is some sales rep is picked the call and pressed some number then only I can connect with person who submitted the form.

Most of the time it is working but for some phones like VIOP its is not working we are thinking like that it is a DTMF tone issue. But How do i Solve this..